# How to save logs to file from "Debug" in my project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I use in my project Debug package https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug.
I set environment variable (variablename: DEBUG & value:*). After this i see in my console output logs from my app. I would like save all this logs to file. How i can make this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many npm packages that can log into files, see for example [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston).

Or you can create your own function that handles where to write the log line - see the [Debug documentation here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug#output-streams)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try a well know library called [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)

Comment: Thanks! Now work only "console.log" without "console.error" and i would like save logs from "morgan" etc. I used the command "node test.js > testLog.log" from "Debug" readme file.